# How to fetch a list of the current users' friends who also use my app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-applications

My requirement is to find the list of friends who installed the application.

Here I need to give the input as application id, based on this application id I need to get the users who have installed this application.

Comment: And what did you try so far? No shown effort and "requirements" to SO, wont get respected here.

Answer (score 6):

Faster than avs099's answer (single call):

Make an API call, using an access token for that app, to `/me/friends?fields=installed` (or `/USER_ID/friends?fields=installed` for an app access token)

Comment: Is there a way to get this to return only users with the app installed instead of all users?  Alternatively, is there a way to get this data with FQL?  I don't really see a 'installed' parameter in the FQL documentation.

Comment: And of course I find the FQL on stackoverflow just moments later:  Select name, uid, pic_small from user where is_app_user = 1 and uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me()) order by concat(first_name,last_name) asc

Comment: @Igy is there a way to retrieve only the ids which currently have the app installed, instead of bringing everyone?

Comment: The FQL query in the comment above yours only returns app users

Comment: This doesn't seem to work any more. When doing `/{APP_ID}/friends?`, I get an error: :"(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (friends) on node type (Application)"

Answer (score 2):

that's relatively easy:

1. Get a list of friends using https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends call (you can use [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) for that)
2. For each friend, get his ID and send a request to the following Graph API: https://graph.facebook.com/FRIEND_ID?access_token=APP_ID|APP_SECRET&**fields=installed**

note: **fields=installed** is required, as per [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)

if you get back something like

> {    "installed": true,    "id": "FRIEND_ID" }

that means that friend has that app installed. If it's just ID coming back - then he does not have app installed.

APP_ID and APP_SECRET can be found on your app's page.

Hope that helps.

Comment: very inefficient way to do i. Igy's answer is way better. Or using FQL.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problem, but was still a little fuzzy on using the Facebook API with FQL. The Facebook FQL page was little to no help, so I went ahead and wrote up a quick solution for those who might be struggling with this in the future.

Suffice it to say, that the long FQL solution can be condensed into a couple lines if you are using the Facebook PHP SDK, which was very nice to see.  [My Facebook API Solution](http://www.crimson-cardinal.com/writings/technology/91-facebook-api-friends-with-my-app)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Koala, you can do this way

In the controller user.rb

```
@user = User.all
```

In the model user.rb

```
def friends_using_app
facebook { |fb| fb.get_connection("me", "friends?fields=installed") }
end
```

In the view

```
 <% friends = current_user.friends_using_app %>
 <% friends_using_app = friends.find_all {|x| x['installed'] == true}    %>
 <% friends_id = friends_using_app.map {|x| x['id']}  %>
 <% show_friends = @user.find_all{|x| x[:uid] = friends_id} %>
 <% show_friends.each do |x| %>
 <%= image_tag x.avatar %>
 <% end %>
```